# SQL Grouping: conditional select in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, grouping

For example, I got a table:

```
Name  , Area,   Age
cat   ,   1 ,    10
dog   ,   2 ,     7
cat   ,   3 ,    11
horse ,   4 ,     4
cat   ,   5 ,    10
dog   ,   6 ,     9
```

When I group by 'Name', for each group I want to retain the 'Area' of the MAX 'Age' in that group. In this example, I wanna get:

```
Name , Area
cat  ,  3
dog  ,  6
horse,  4
```

How should I do this in one query? Thanks guys!

Comment: @SamD I don't need max age, I want the 'Area' of the max age per group. In your query the 'Area' is randomly selected from each group..

Comment: @SamD That query will not work as expected. The area will be random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT name, area FROM mytable
JOIN (
    SELECT name, MAX(age) as maxage FROM mytable
    GROUP BY name
) AS `max`
ON  mytable.name = max.name AND mytable.age = max.maxage
```

This first selects the `name` and `MAX(age)` in a subquery, and then joins them to the original table so that you can get the `area` associated with the `MAX(age)`. By using `join` ie `inner join`, we insure that any results in the original table that had nothing to match do not show.

Notice that you can't do something like:

```
SELECT name, MAX(age), area FROM mytable
```

Because `area` would be randomly selected from all the `area` values in the group. It wouldn't know which `area` you want. You might think that it would get you the `area` in the same row as the `MAX(age)`, but it will not. It doesn't actually know that is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This would be more slightly more efficient than the subquery approach mentioned by @deroby and @DamienBlack:

```
SELECT t1.name, t1.area
FROM myTable t1
LEFT JOIN myTable t2 
  ON t1.name = t2.name AND t2.Age > t1.Age
WHERE t2.some_primary_key IS NULL
ORDER BY t1.name
```

Note that this requires some column known to contain a value that is not NULL (such as a primary key).  You can substitute, `t2.some_primary_key` with any other non-null, indexed column as needed.

SQLFiddle based off @deroby's [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b32156/2).

Comment: Although the execution plan on MSSQL (++) seems to agree with you, the result of this query isn't quite correct (yet). [++: not a clue on how to compare this on mysql]

Comment: That is a clever solution as well. I wonder what the performance difference is.

Comment: Indeed, plugging `SELECT t1.Name, t1.Area
FROM test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 
  ON t1.Name = t2.Name AND t2.Age > t1.Age
WHERE t2.Name IS NULL` into the sqlFiddle returns the same information now. +1 =)

Comment: @DamienBlack - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8749095/1141839) from Bill Karwin on this point.

Comment: On MSSQL the query plans differ quite a bit. The question off course is how (if?) indexing and volumes might affect this. [QueryPlan](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/747955/Stuff%20shared%20in%20forums%20%28do%20NOT%20delete%2C%20keep%20small%21%29/SO-QueryPlan.png)

Comment: @deroby - as this question applies to MySQL, you can refer to the link I referenced above. To be sure, there should be a compound index on name and age for this to work efficiently...

Comment: I know, but I simply don't have mysql here, nor know how to compare the performance of queries. Somehow I would assume non-exotic queries perform (relatively) alike in the different products. FYI: After indexing the difference between both queries is rather similar ... on MSSQL =) [QueryPlan w Indexes](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/747955/Stuff%20shared%20in%20forums%20%28do%20NOT%20delete%2C%20keep%20small%21%29/SO-QueryPlanIndexed.png)

Comment: You would need a larger set of data before you saw a material difference.  But you should know that every DBMS query planner is _not_ alike even for commonly used strategies - [here is one interesting example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null/2246793#2246793).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47193/discussion-between-deroby-and-pinnym)

Answer (score 0):

Seems I need to learn to type faster =)

Anyway, I came up with this; you can test it [in this sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21cc7/2%)

```
 SELECT t.Name, t.Area
  FROM (SELECT Name, Max(Age) as Max_Age
          FROM test
         GROUP BY Name) mx
  JOIN test t
    ON t.Name = mx.Name
   AND t.Age  = mx.Max_Age
 ORDER BY t.Name
```

Comment: thanks, this is almost the same query with @DamienBlack's.  Worked well.

Comment: Yeah, it pretty much IS the same, but at least he explained what it does, and typed faster =). 

Then again, I have a sqlFiddle =P. Anyway, please do take PinnyM's comments into account about performance. It may work great now on 100 records but cause headaches once you're a couple of months into production with bunch-loads of records.