# SQL group by with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am working with visitor log data and need to summarize it by IP address. The data looks like this:

```
id        | ip_address     | type     | message  | ...
----------+----------------+----------+----------------
1         | 1.2.3.4        | purchase | ...
2         | 1.2.3.4        | visit    | ...
3         | 3.3.3.3        | visit    | ...
4         | 3.3.3.3        | purchase | ...
5         | 4.4.4.4        | visit    | ...
6         | 4.4.4.4        | visit    | ...
```

And should summarize with:

```
type="purchase" DESC, type="visit" DESC, id DESC
```

The yield:

```
chosenid  | ip_address     | type     | message  | ...
----------+----------------+----------+----------------
1         | 1.2.3.4        | purchase | ...
4         | 3.3.3.3        | purchase | ...
6         | 4.4.4.4        | visit    | ...
```

**Is there an elegant way to get this data?**

---

An ugly approach follows:

```
set @row_num = 0; 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tt AS 
SELECT *,@row_num:=@row_num+1 as row_index FROM log ORDER BY type="purchase" DESC, type="visit" DESC, id DESC
ORDER BY rating desc;
```

Then get the minimum row_index and id for each ip_address (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

Then join those id's back to the original table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be what you need:

```
SELECT yourtable.*
FROM
  yourtable INNER JOIN (
    SELECT   ip_address,
             MAX(CASE WHEN type='purchase' THEN id END) max_purchase,
             MAX(CASE WHEN type='visit' THEN id END) max_visit
    FROM     yourtable
    GROUP BY ip_address) m
  ON yourtable.id = COALESCE(max_purchase, max_visit)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a637/1).

My subquery will return the maximum purchase id (or null if there's no purchase) and the maximum visit id. Then I'm joining the table with COALESCE, if max_purchase is not null the join will be on max_purchase, otherwise it will be on max_visit.

Comment: This is the most straightforward. Very nice approach, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bill Karwin's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749095/1141839) here:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (SELECT *, CASE WHEN type = 'purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_purchase FROM myTable) t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT *, CASE WHEN type = 'purchase' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END is_purchase FROM myTable) t2
  ON t1.ip_address = t2.ip_address
  AND (t2.is_purchase > t1.is_purchase
     OR (t2.is_purchase = t1.is_purchase AND t2.id > t1.id))
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd7d6b/1)

Answer (score 0):

The following query gets the most recent `id` based on your rules by using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.ip_adddress,
       (select t2.id
        from table t2
        where t2.ip_address = t1.ip_address
        order by type = 'purchase' desc, id desc
        limit 1
       ) as mostrecent
from (select distinct t.ip_address
      from table t
     ) t;
```

The idea is to sort the data first by purchases (with id descending too) and then by visits and choose the first one in the list.  If you have a table of ipaddresses, then you don't need the `distinct` subquery.  Just use that table instead.

To get the final results, we can `join` to this or use `in` or `exists`.  This uses `in`.

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select id, (select t2.id
                  from table t2
                  where t2.ip_address = t1.ip_address
                  order by type = 'purchase' desc, id desc
                  limit 1
                 ) as mostrecent
      from (select distinct t.ip_address
            from table t
           ) t
     ) ids
     on t.id = ids.mostrecent;
```

This query will work best if there is an index on `table(ip_address, type, id)`.