# SELECT newest rows, ignore old duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates, distinct

In my table, i have the following columns :

```
CRMID | user | ticket_id | | description | date | hour
```

what i am trying to do is to select all the rows from the table, but when two (or more) rows have the same `ticket_id`, i want only the newest one to appear in the results, so the row with the newest date and hour.

the problem here is that i should be addin cases, if the values from the date column are the same, then i will compare the hour colum, otherwise, its simple cauz i'll be comparing only the date column.

Comment: What are the data types for the `date` and `hour` columns?

Comment: date is date type, and hour is in time type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get records with highest/smallest <whatever> per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748986/get-records-with-highest-smallest-whatever-per-group)

Answer (score 2):

```
  SELECT 
    n.*
FROM 
    table n RIGHT JOIN  (
       SELECT 
         MAX(date) AS max_date,
         (SELECT MAX(hour) AS hour WHERE date = max_date) AS hour,
         user,
         ticket_id 
       FROM
         table
       GROUP BY
         user,
         ticket_id
       ) m ON n.user = m.user AND n.ticket_id = m.ticket_id
```

Comment: This looks alot better than mine! :)

Comment: It's not working, here is my querry till now
select distinct t.ticket_id, t.id 
from  tickets t 
where not exists (SELECT 1
from tickets t1 where t.date < t1.date and t.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id
)

Comment: what i still need id the hour condition

Comment: Here is the working query :
SELECT DISTINCT t.ticket_id, t.id
FROM tickets t
WHERE NOT
EXISTS (

SELECT 1
FROM tickets t1
WHERE (
t.date < t1.date
OR (
t.date = t1.date
AND t.heure < t1.heure
)
)
AND (
t.ticket_id = t1.ticket_id
)
)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to combine your date and hour columns, then perform the comparison

```
SELECT foo.*
FROM foo
JOIN (SELECT ticket_id, MAX(ADDTIME(`date`,`hour`)) as mostrecent
      FROM foo
      GROUP BY ticket_id) AS bar
ON bar.ticket_id = foo.ticket_id
  and bar.mostrecent = ADDTIME(foo.`date`,foo.`hour`);
```