# Is there a way to query Solr for a document with the most recent time field?

Tags: solr, solrj

If my solr documents has a

```
<field name="timestamp" type="solr.TrieDateField" indexed="true" stored="true"  required="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

how can i query for the most recent document?

Only way I've discovered so far is to sort by descending date and limit rows to 1 but that has some limitations when i want something like get the most recent version of documents with id 1,2,3,4

something similar to this [Get records with highest/smallest <whatever> per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748986/get-records-with-highest-smallest-whatever-per-group)

Comment: Shouldn`t you begin with sorting by **descending** date ?

Comment: Sorry you're right must've not been thinking when i wrote the question, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have gotten the results im looking for by using a solr group query

```
  group=true&group.field=groupId&group.sort=timestamp desc
```