# Count Number of Consecutive Occurrence of values in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregation

I have below table

```
create table #t (Id int, Name char)

insert into #t values
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'B'),
(4, 'B'),
(5, 'B'),
(6, 'B'),
(7, 'C'),
(8, 'B'),
(9, 'B')
```

I want to count consecutive values in name column

```
+------+------------+
| Name | Repetition |
+------+------------+
| A    |          2 |
| B    |          4 |
| C    |          1 |
| B    |          2 |
+------+------------+
```

The best thing I tried is:

```
select Name
, COUNT(*) over (partition by Name order by Id) AS Repetition
from #t
order by Id
```

but it doesn't give me expected result

Comment: I have the same needs but it's in google sheets, haha

Answer (score 59, accepted):

One approach is the difference of row numbers:

```
select name, count(*) 
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by name order by id)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp, name;
```

The logic is easiest to understand if you run the subquery and look at the values of each row number separately and then look at the difference.

Comment: With `order by max(id)` added, the result would look exactly like in the OP's post (involving the order of the records).

Comment: @KingKing, thanks for your hint. Yes, it makes it exactly like what I need.

Comment: Why my query doesn't give me the result, I expect when I partition by Name, the count(*) should reset when the values of Name changes. I appreciate if you explain that. Thanks again.

Comment: @FLICKER . . . I think if you run your query, you should understand.  It enumerates the names regardless of gaps between rows.  That is, it ignores gaps.

Comment: This solution doesn't work for this example:
A, A, B, B, B, A, B

Comment: @AhmadRezaSaboor . . . It certainly should.  If you have a question, though, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't think a new question is required. Just calculate the grp values for my example and you'll understand where the issue is. The grp values are: 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3.

Comment: @AhmadRezaSaboor
Would wrapping the query in another one and then partitioning by id and grp not fix this issue?  
Something like select *,count(1) over (partition by id,grp) as correct_consec from ...

Comment: This is the best solution. How can we do this using self join? Someone asked me this question in an interview.

Comment: @vijayraj34 i don't think self-join would give you this particular result (consecutive occurrences of any value). Self-join CAN give you the extremity (max/min, first/last, etc.) record of each record group: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8749095/258598

Comment: @AhmadReza I was confused at some point as well. Your group values calculations were correct, but note that the final, outermost query would group by both group value and name. So it would work.

Comment: This doesn't work for all cases. Fails for this: 
insert into aberration_detection_system.temp_x  values
(1, '0'),
(2, '3'),
(3, '2'),
(4, '2'),
(5, '2'),
(6, '2'),
(7, '2'),
(8, '1'),
(9, '0')
;

Answer (score 17):

You could use windowed functions like `LAG` and running total:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT Id, Name, grp = SUM(CASE WHEN Name = prev THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER(ORDER BY id)
 FROM (SELECT *, prev = LAG(Name) OVER(ORDER BY id) FROM t) s
)
SELECT name, cnt = COUNT(*)
FROM cte
GROUP BY grp,name
ORDER BY grp;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f9f74f6f7e8d81e16bb06aefd2f54d0d)**

The first cte returns group number:

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| Id  | Name  | grp |
+-----+-------+-----+
|  1  | A     |   1 |
|  2  | A     |   1 |
|  3  | B     |   2 |
|  4  | B     |   2 |
|  5  | B     |   2 |
|  6  | B     |   2 |
|  7  | C     |   3 |
|  8  | B     |   4 |
|  9  | B     |   4 |
+-----+-------+-----+
```

And main query groups it based on `grp` column calculated earlier:

```
+-------+-----+
| name  | cnt |
+-------+-----+
| A     |   2 |
| B     |   4 |
| C     |   1 |
| B     |   2 |
+-------+-----+
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly fine, while the accepted answer fails for some cases. Thanks. @FLICKER You should select this as accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

I have use Recursive CTE and minimise the use of row_number,also avoid count(*).

I think it will perform better,but in real world it depend what else filter you put to minimise number of rows affected.

If ID is having discreet values then One extra CTE will be use to generate continuous id.

```
 ;With CTE2 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by id) id, name,1 Repetition ,1 Marker  from @t
)
, CTE as
(
select top 1 cast(id as int) id, name,1 Repetition ,1 Marker  from CTE2 order by id

union all

select a.id, a.name
, case when a.name=c.name then Repetition +1 else 1 end  
, case when a.name=c.name then c.Marker else  Marker+1 end
from @t a
inner join CTE c on a.id=c.id+1

)
,CTE1 as
(select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by marker order by id desc)rn from cte c
)
select Name,Repetition from cte1 where rn=1
```