# Select count of consecutive events based on time column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my data :

```
app_id  event_type  event_time
1       event1      2020-22-03 04:05:03
1       event3      2020-22-03 04:05:04
1       event2      2020-22-03 04:05:05
1       event3      2020-22-03 04:05:10
1       event1      2020-22-03 04:05:11
1       event2      2020-22-03 04:05:12
2       event3      2020-22-03 04:05:04
```

I want to count the sum of two events for each `app_id` :

1. Number of `event3`
2. Number of `event1` followed immediately (based on `event_time`) by `event2`

With the data above, the output would be :

```
app_id  count
1       3 <--- (2 * event3 + event1 followed by event2)
2       1
```

The number of `event3` can be calculated with :

```sql
SELECT app_id,
    count(event_type = 'event3')
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY app_id;
```

For the second count, I guess the data need to be `GROUP BY app_id` combined with `ORDERBY event_time`

I also saw other answers for checking consecutive values ([Count Number of Consecutive Occurrence of values in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927685/count-number-of-consecutive-occurrence-of-values-in-table)), but I couldn't adapt it to my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CTE` where you convert the 2 conditions to integers 0 or 1 which then will be aggregated:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
    (event_type = 'event3')::int is_event3,
    (event_type = 'event1' AND LEAD(event_type) OVER (PARTITION BY app_id ORDER BY event_time) = 'event2')::int is_event1_event2
  FROM test_table   
)  
SELECT app_id, SUM(is_event3 + is_event1_event2) "count"
FROM cte
GROUP BY app_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8xGkfHRm6wyX7ysCrfrgGQ/3).
Results:

```
| app_id | count |
| ------ | ----- |
| 1      | 3     |
| 2      | 1     |
```