# Find the Biggest Number of Consecutive Occurrence of values in Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregation

I have the following table

```
create table Launches (Id int, Name char)

insert into Launches values
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'A'),
(3, 'B'),
(4, 'B'),
(5, 'B'),
(6, 'B'),
(7, 'C'),
(8, 'B'),
(9, 'B')
```

The result should be

4 - B

From 3 to 6

Similar question -

[Count Number of Consecutive Occurrence of values in Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927685/count-number-of-consecutive-occurrence-of-values-in-table)

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show us your research and attempt.

Comment: The question you have linked to tells you how to do it?

Comment: It doesn't because it does not report where the biggest consecutive sequence starts and ends. In my real life case the letter "B" repeats many times in many places and without the indexes I can't localize the biggest sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract an enumerated value for each `name` to get a constant for adjacent values that are the same.  The rest is aggregation:

```
select top (1) name, count(*), min(id), max(id)
from (select l.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as seqnum
      from #Launches l
     ) l
group by (id - seqnum), name
order by count(*) desc;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e99553c9b91ffa9310fb623b48a65e30) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That is a great script! However for me is equally important to know the first and the last index - 3 and 6 in this example

Comment: @JoeJobs . . . Just include that in the `select`.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, really

Comment: @JoeJobs Gordan has already done it for you - check his edits. However it sounds like you might benefit more from checking out some SQL tutorials and learning the basics, because sure people will answer your questions here, but you won't gain the skills to do it yourself that way.

Comment: Thanks, I cant edit the answer, it should be "Launches" instead of "#Launches"

Comment: It says I have to change at least 6 characters in order to be able to save it. And yes I upvoted the answer. I was told to wait a few days until accepting an answer, to encourage more users to answer the question

Comment: "Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?"

Comment: @JoeJobs . . . I don't understand.  The question uses `#Launches`.  The code in the fiddle is slightly different, but it really is not hard to change the table name in a query.

Comment: My bad, I copied from the other question, now I replaced #Launches with Launches in the question. The "#" ony complicates things, it is better without it. I just wanted to make sure that copying the code in that fiddle it works without modification.