# Count contiguous occurrences of the same value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, lag, gaps-and-islands

Using SQL Server 2019 Standard edition. I am collecting moon measurements from the moons and need to detect the number of times a test has failed *contiguously* over a nine intervals (or series).  A numeral one indicates a failure.

There's test data here in this table, and my expected output query is further below. Very important to understand *contiguously* here.  If a test fails (1 is reported) on 5,7 and 9 but not on 6 and 8 then it is not counted.  Implicitly, 1 is, therefor, not a valid result.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpTable

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable 
(
    mooniq int,
    testresult int,
    series bigint
)

INSERT INTO #tmpTable (mooniq, testresult, series) 
VALUES
(74904, NULL, 1),
(74904, NULL, 2),
(74904, NULL, 3),
(74904, NULL, 4),
(74904, 1, 5),
(74904, 1, 6),
(74904, 1, 7),
(74904, NULL, 8),
(74904, NULL, 9),
(94904, NULL, 1),
(94904, NULL, 2),
(94904, NULL, 3),
(94904, NULL, 4),
(94904, 1, 5),
(94904, 1, 6),
(94904, 1, 7),
(94904, 1, 8),
(94904, 1, 9),
(24904, NULL, 1),
(24904, NULL, 2),
(24904, NULL, 3),
(24904, NULL, 4),
(24904, 1, 5),
(24904, NULL, 6),
(24904, 1, 7),
(24904, NULL, 8),
(24904, 1, 9);
```

I'm trying to get the query's output to match this query's output:

```
--- The results should look like this query's results
/*
mooniq  contiqs
------  -------
24904   0  
74904   3
94904   5
*/
SELECT 'mooniq' = 74904, 'contiqs' = 3
UNION
SELECT 'mooniq' = 94904 , 'contigs' = 5
UNION
SELECT 'mooniq' = 24904 , 'contigs' = 0
```

So far I've tried the approach laid out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927685/count-number-of-consecutive-occurrence-of-values-in-table) and am not successful with the ornery mooniq '24904'  because although it has 3 failures, none of those are contiguous, and so should not be counted.

```
--An ambiguation of a business problem simplified for you
--So far I've tried:
with grouped_moons as (
 select mooniq, 
          testresult,
          dense_rank() over (order BY mooniq,series) drom ,
          dense_rank() over (partition by testresult order by mooniq, series)  DRPQ 
                  from #tmpTable t)
select * from grouped_moons order by mooniq
```

Comment: SQL Server 2019!

Comment: Thanks fellas.  I'm writing it for the reader (you)   This is all my own work and a subset of a subtly more complex problem.  I try to carve out as little as necessary and think maybe my carving was a bit wayward.  It's all fixed now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes.  A numeral one indicates a failure.  It doesn't count as any because, and this is the hard part and the heart of my resiliency on the topic,  it is not contiguous.  It fails on 5,7 and 9 but not on 6 and 8.

Comment: Correct. 1 is never a valid result.

Comment: Thank you!  I am going to work on it this afternoon and will keep you informed.  Also,  your "There is some value in something being heavy handed but obvious" is spot-on and should be a book title.

Comment: I tested and adapted all these solutions into the greater context and things work wonderfully irrespective of approach. Thank you for your help and creativity!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as getting the method you were using working, you have two additional problems to solve:

1. You could get multiple groups per `mooniq` (as opposed to the example which only has one).
2. You need to convert 1 to 0 (mostly trivial)

So you need to use an additional sub-query / CTE to find the max of the groups within a `mooniq` e.g.

```
with cte1 as (
  select mooniq, count(*) numrows
  from (
    select t.*
      , row_number() over (partition by mooniq order by series) -
        row_number() over (partition by mooniq, testresult order by series)
      as grp
    from #tmpTable t
  ) t
  where testresult = 1
  group by grp, mooniq
)
select mooniq, max(case when numrows = 1 then 0 else numrows end)
from cte1
group by mooniq;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what's intuitive to me. The linked answer is very clever and certainly better, more succinct and probably more performant because it doesn't need an additional join. There is some value in something being heavy handed but obvious though.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/8KvQo9Oq (has a corrected approach for the linked answer as well)

The rationale is, since you already have a sequence number, just do an inline subquery to get the sequence value of the last pass case. The difference between the a failing row's sequence number and the last passing sequence number is your fail streak. The max fail streak by mooniq is your longest consecutive fail streak.

Returns null instead of 0 for the singular failures, but you can of course coalesce() or tweak as needed.

```
with cte as (
    select *,
           case when t1.testresult = 1 then 
           coalsece(
           (
           select max(t2.series)
             from #tmpTable t2
            where t1.mooniq = t2.mooniq
              and t1.series > t2.series
              and t2.testresult is null
           ), 0) end as last_pass_series_from_a_fail
      from #tmpTable t1
)
select mooniq,
       nullif(max(series - last_pass_series_from_a_fail),1) as continous_fail
  from cte
 where testresult = 1
 group
    by mooniq
```

Comment: So I learned this query returns inaccurate results when all of a moon's test fail.  I don't know if it is appropriate for me to go add this additional data to the test data.

Answer (score 1):

Far from the simplest approach, but using a traditional gaps-and-islands approach, this builds up the solution in a logical manner as follows

1. Find each transition of `testresult` to or from 1
2. Use this transition to allocate a unique group number to each group of values
3. Row number each group
4. Take the max row number

```
with cte1 as (
  select mooniq, series, testresult
    -- Find when the testresult changes
    , case when coalesce(testresult,-1) <> coalesce(lag(testresult, 1, testresult) over (partition by mooniq order by series), -1) then 1 else 0 end Change
  from #tmpTable
), cte2 as (
  select mooniq, series, testresult
    -- Give it a unique group number
    , case when testresult = 1 then sum(Change) over (partition by mooniq order by series rows between unbounded preceding and current row) else null end GroupToCount
  from cte1
), cte3 as (
  select mooniq, series, testresult
    -- Then row number within each unique group
    , row_number() over (partition by mooniq, GroupToCount order by series) rn
  from cte2
)
-- Then take the max of row number of each group, converting 1 into 0
select mooniq, case when max(rn) = 1 then 0 else max(rn) end
from cte3
where testresult = 1
group by mooniq
order by mooniq;
```