Count consecutive number of True flags for each day before False occurs
Could you please help me with the following SQL task. Here's a data table:
|     date      |   hour   |   flag   |
|---------------|----------|----------|
|   2024-04-13  |    23    |   True   |
|   2024-04-13  |    22    |   True   |
|   2024-04-13  |    21    |   True   |
|   2024-04-13  |    20    |   False  |
|   2024-04-13  |    19    |   True   |
|   2024-04-13  |    18    |   True   |
|-------------------------------------|
|   2024-04-12  |    20    |   False  |
|   2024-04-12  |    19    |   True   |
|   2024-04-12  |    18    |   True   |
|   2024-04-12  |    17    |   True   |
|   2024-04-12  |    16    |   True   |
|   2024-04-12  |    15    |   True   |
|-------------------------------------|
|   2024-04-11  |    22    |   True   |
|   2024-04-11  |    18    |   True   |
|   2024-04-11  |    15    |   False  |
|   2024-04-11  |    10    |   True   |
|   2024-04-11  |     9    |   False  |
|   2024-04-11  |     8    |   True   |
|-------------------------------------|
|   2024-04-10  |    10    |   True   |
|   2024-04-10  |    9     |   True   |
|   2024-04-10  |    6     |   True   |
|   2024-04-10  |    3     |   False  |
|-------------------------------------|

What I need is to count, for each day, how many consecutive True flags there are before any False flag occurence (from the top). So, the result should look like this:
|     date      |   count  |
|---------------|----------|
|   2024-04-13  |     3    |
|   2024-04-12  |     0    |
|   2024-04-11  |     2    |
|   2024-04-10  |     3    |

Notes: Hour is ordered descending, but there may be holes, as in e.g. 2024-04-11 (still the result is 2, we're counting the rows).
Thank you in advance.

Maybe we can use this fiddle to collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/Ikagj1t_

Please tag your RDBMS, see here why that's important: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

This question seems similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927685/count-number-of-consecutive-occurrence-of-values-in-table

This is a gaps and islands problem. Unfortunately, I have some kind of mental block and have to look up how to do it every time. But now you know the name of the issue, you can do that just a quickly as I.

As 'False' < 'True' we can use min() over to get a running min
select date, count(case f when 'True' then f end) n
from ( 
  select *, 
    min(flag) over(partition by date order by hour desc rows unbounded preceding) f
  from datatable
) t
group by date
order by date desc

db<>fiddle

You can do something like this perhaps:
SELECT  date, max(countOver) AS TruthFlags
FROM    (
    SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN flag = 'True' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY hour DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
        * CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN flag = 'False' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY hour DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS countOver
    ,   *
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (N'2024-04-13', 23, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-13', 22, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-13', 21, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-13', 20, N'False')
        ,   (N'2024-04-13', 19, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-13', 18, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-12', 20, N'False')
        ,   (N'2024-04-12', 19, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-12', 18, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-12', 17, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-12', 16, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-12', 15, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-11', 22, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-11', 18, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-11', 15, N'False')
        ,   (N'2024-04-11', 10, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-11', 9, N'False')
        ,   (N'2024-04-11', 8, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-10', 10, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-10', 9, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-10', 6, N'True')
        ,   (N'2024-04-10', 3, N'False')
    ) t (date,hour,flag)
) x
group by date

My idea is to create a "zeroer" running total of False flags, which goes from last hour to the first. This expression: CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN flag = 'False' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY hour DESC) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END creates a 0 value if there has been false flags and 1 otherwise.
Then all one need is to multiple the zeroer with the current number of True flags.
Finally, I use max(countOver) to find the peak aggregated True number of flags.

I used CTEs to make groups and find the maximum hour for each date. This solution is more general and can be easily modified to work for non-boolean columns.
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT date,
       [hour],
       flag, 
      abs(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY flag ORDER BY [Date] desc, hour desc) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Date] ORDER BY [Date] desc, hour desc )  
      ) as grp
FROM datatable
), MaxHourPerDate as
(
  SELECT date,
       max(hour) as maxHour
  FROM datatable
  GROUP BY [date]
), 
truefalsecount as 
(  
SELECT c.[date], max(hour) as maxhour, c.flag, c.grp, count(*) as rc
FROM CTE c
GROUP BY c.[date], c.flag, c.grp
)
SELECT t.date, CASE flag WHEN 'True' then t.rc ELSE 0 END as [count] 
FROM truefalsecount t
INNER JOIN MaxHourPerDate m ON m.[date]=t.[date] and t.maxhour=m.maxhour
ORDER BY t.[date] desc

fiddle



date
count




2024-04-13
3


2024-04-12
0


2024-04-11
2


2024-04-10
3



