# select row based on oldest timestamp per name

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pick the rows based on the oldest timestamp per name. I referred this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748986/get-records-with-highest-smallest-whatever-per-group) but the problem is my table doesn't have id column. I tried to add an temp auto increment id column but was not sure how to do it. basically when the timestamp is same I want to pick any one of the available records for the given name. Can someone please help me out here.

```
mysql> select * from tblemployee order by name;
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| name | day_of_week | signin_date         |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| bob  | wednesday   | 2017-08-11 08:11:30 |
| bob  | thursday    | 2017-06-11 11:21:30 | << same timestamp
| bob  | saturday    | 2017-08-28 09:01:30 |
| bob  | wednesday   | 2017-08-11 08:11:30 |
| bob  | monday      | 2017-06-11 11:21:30 | << same timestamp
| tom  | wednesday   | 2017-08-28 23:01:20 |
| tom  | sunday      | 2017-08-29 09:01:30 |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
```

My expected result would be something like this

**For 'tom'**

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| name | day_of_week | signin_date         |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| tom  | wednesday   | 2017-08-28 23:01:20 |
```

**For 'bob'** since there are two records with same timestamp , I can pick any one irrespective of day_of_week.

```
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| name | day_of_week | signin_date         |
+------+-------------+---------------------+
| bob  | thursday    | 2017-06-11 11:21:30 |

                    (or)

| bob  | monday      | 2017-06-11 11:21:30 |
```

Comment: Do you want just one person (bob) or a set of people?  for 1, ORDER BY and LIMIT 1.  I'm guessing  from "rows" you want both bob and tom, but it isn't 100% clear to me.

Comment: I would like to pick one record for each user based on oldest timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can use a join on the group value for min(signin_date) eg:

```
  select distinct a.name, a.day_of_week , a.signin_date         
  from tblemployee a
  inner join (
    select name, min(signin_date) as min_date
    from tblemployee
    group by name
  ) t on t.min_date = a.signin_date and a.name = t.name
```

if you have ambiguos rows  as for bob the min(signin_date) i related  to two different day then you should get one of this using

```
  select a.name, min(a.day_of_week) , a.signin_date         
  from tblemployee a
  inner join (
    select name, min(signin_date) as min_date
    from tblemployee
    group by name
  ) t on t.min_date = a.signin_date and a.name = t.name 
  group by a.name,a.signin_date
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to work for me. The columns get duplicated and i see record related to bob appearing twice.

Comment: Thanks, the column names look good now but I still see the query returning two records in case of name 'bob'.

Comment: this because Bob has 2 lines with the same value ( bob  | wednesday   | 2017-08-11 08:11:30).. is it a mistake or is it a situation to handle ??

Comment: actually the two records of bob are ( bob  | monday      | 2017-06-11 11:21:30 ) and ( bob  | thursday    | 2017-06-11 11:21:30) , in this case i need to pick any one of those.

Comment: i don't understand ..  as result you want a single row for each name  or not?and please update you data sample so i can evaluate the right one  .. i can't imagine what you are doing ..

Comment: anyway  i have update the answer  adding a new suggestion for ambigous min date

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my original post with details. And now I see your newly updated query seem to meet my requirement.