# Create one row from multiple rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm want to create one row that includes all the latest data from my table, I found the way to do it separately for each column, is it possible to do it in one query?

[image]

This will be the wanted answer table:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) Same problem, you're just looking for "last" rather than first.

Comment: @Uueerdo Since that is for Postgres I don't think that's the right duplicate link. It's definitely a duplicate though, but this one is closer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: A more helpful "duplicate" SO-post is probably this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748986/get-records-with-highest-smallest-whatever-per-group/8749095#8749095 as it refers to MySQL.

Comment: @Error_2646 that answer has a vendor-agnostic version as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *correlated* subquery :

```
select t.*
from table t
where time1 = (select max(t1.time1) from table t1 where t1.p_id = t.p_id);
```

Comment: in this case my ccc column will be empty because there is no data for ccc where  max time1 for p_id = 1

Answer (score 1):

if you need the rows related  to max_daye 
you could use a join with the subquery for max time1

```
select   m.p_id, m.aaa, m.bbb, m.ccc 
from mytable m
inner join (
  SELECT p_id,  max(time1) max_date 
  FROM   mytable
  group by p_id 
) t on t.max_date =  m.time1  and t.p_id = m.p_id
```

or if you need  only the max vale for each p_id  you can use

```
select   m.p_id, max(m.aaa), max(m.bbb), max(m.ccc )
from mytable m
group by m-p_id
```

Comment: the problem is that not all the columns are full, in this case for p_id 1 the ccc column will be empty

Comment: then you need only the max value for each p_id  ... answer updated   .. hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

You could use correlated subqueries fetching the "latest" non null values for each column for each distinct ID.

```
SELECT t1.p_id,
       (SELECT t2.aaa
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.p_id = t1.p_id
                     AND t2.aaa IS NOT NULL
               ORDER BY t2.time1 DESC
               LIMIT 1) aaa,
       ...
       (SELECT t2.ccc
               FROM elbat t2
               WHERE t2.p_id = t1.p_id
                     AND t2.ccc IS NOT NULL
               ORDER BY t2.time1 DESC
               LIMIT 1) ccc,
       FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                    p_id
                    FROM elbat) t1;
```